# Diplaying options in navbar when user connected Passport Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, ejs, navbar

I want my navbar to display "Profile of : {USER}" if someone is connected, else a set of Sing up/ Login tab.

Point is: I'm using EJS, with separate "head.ejs" and "header.ejs" esctions in a /partial folder put in the /views folder.

On the index.ejs, I can display what I early pass with:

```
res.render('index.ejs', {username: req.user.username})
```

But I've not succeeded yet to pass this "username from my index.ejs to my header.ejs, where my navbar is.

My other issue is the loging going on my navbar (I use an isLoggedin), I have an : Function isLoggedin is not defined.

Any help or hint is very welcome ! :)

EDIT :
So far, I got my header.ejs :

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/stock">Stock</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/registerUser">Add User ADMIN ONLY</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <span class="nav-link"> Profile of :  <%=username %> </span>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Logout</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This is my index.ejs (partial/head is plain HTML)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <%- include('./partial/head'); %>

  </head>

  <body>
    <head>
      <%- include('./partial/header',{username: username}); %>
    </head>
```

Then this is my get index part of code :

```
    app.get('/', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  db.collection('installations').find().toArray()
    .then(results => {
      res.render('index.ejs', {installation: results,username: 
req.user.username})
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
})
```

Comment: you can send the username information to index.ejs. Ejs is smart, it automatically takes value from the res.render statement.

Comment: Yes, Now I have it working... But It crashes as soon as I logout .. I've been thinking to make two "headers.ejs", one for an user is connected and the other one generic, but I'm not sure if this is a good solution/practice .. I'm sure there is some kind of way to use some script to display the name in the navbar the name of the user when he's connected an otherwise the link for him to connect himself

Comment: you can use ternary operator of if condition with the particular div. ie, ``` <% (userId == session.user.id) { %> <div>Logedin</div> <% } else { %> Login/Signup  <% }%> ``` hope it helps.

Comment: @xetryDcoder I tried your solution, it gave me the  _userId is not defined_ error.. What do you call userID ? is it something you pass from the APP ? Something like :  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61292315/insert-username-in-a-ejs-template-with-express-and-node-js)

Comment: That was just an example. <% if(username) { %> <div><%= username %> </div> <% } else { %> Login/Signup <% }%> . you Can try this one if this doesnt help push your project to git and share the link.. i might help you

Comment: Your solution works when someone is connected, but when not I have the same problem. The app cannot pass an username to the ejs to display, and I think that it does not pass anything at all. For example: 'app.get("/login", function(req, res){
    res.render("login",{firstName:req.user.firstName})})'  gives me :  *TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined* because there is nothing to pass to the ejs ..

Comment: can you ```console.log(result)``` above this line ```res.render('index.ejs', {installation: results,username: 
req.user.username})``` . What output we get?

Comment: 'results' is an array of the Schema installation that I use in my app, then I use EJS to diplay the components of each item stored in the array. It's not related to my navbar problem =)

Answer (score 0):

try putting in:

```js
"Profile of : {{username}}"
```

Comment: Hello, using the double parethesis did not worked for me, I used '<%=username%>' but now I thats has been inplemented in every view of my site, if I logout I've this error message : _TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined_ .. Any idea of how I can solve this ?

Comment: Hopefully you already have body-parser installed, check that your paths are below the body-parser code in your main file, or if not, it may be because username is asynchronous.

Comment: perhaps this will help:     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867172/node-express-js-cannot-read-property-username-of-undefined

Comment: No, the error comes from the fact that, when logged out, ther is no username to display, since there is no user (the app cannot send req.user.username when rendering an ejs page)

Comment: I saw this post, I already had the app. use before using my route or my express-session. I genuinelly think that the error si from the fact that there is nobody conected, hence no username to send via ejs for displaying .. But I dont knw how to solve this if not making two separate pages , one for being connected and one not... But I'm not pleased with the idea

Comment: creates a condition, if no user name exists it creates an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done :

In the Login page, I've made a custom navbar, since everything is useless inf your not connected. So, I've put an IsLoggedIn function on every page that I wanted to display the user name, so that an unauthentified user is automatically redirected to th login page.

Not the most elegant solution, but I was not pleased with creating an empty object to pass. Still, it's working.